# Pine-script: Automatic zoom on y axis according to min and max levels of candlesticks

Tags: pine-script

Can an indicator perform an automatic zoom of the y axis by choosing y min level as the min value of the candlesticks (incl. wicks) on the chart, and similarly the y max level as the max value of the candlesticks? If so, how can this be coded used Pine Scripts?

This could be the solution written in Matlab (but I obviously need it in Pine Script):

```
ymin = min(close)
ymax = max(close)
plot(...)
ylim([ymin ymax])
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this cannot be done in Pine, because there's no Pine code available that allows interaction with the chart or the axises.
You can see a list of all available commands in the [Pine Script language reference manual](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/)

Comment: Can I then instead go N candles back, extract minimum and maximum (price) from that range, add and subtract Z percent in price to allow for some white space (necessary if min/max is latest candle), as reference points? Oh sorry, that still does not link with the chart y-axis...

Comment: Indeed. Wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround:

Deselect "Scale price chart only" option on the y-axis.

Plot min and max values on the chart using pine script.

Control the zoom level using the min and max values to desired levels.